# Handling (serializing, actually..) DeserializationException in akka-http

Tags: json, scala, akka, akka-http, spray-json

I have a need to encode exception messages in to a specific JSON format in my http responses. I was wondering how I could catch a DeserializationException in my route or outside of it or encode the DeserializationException.

I tried the following:

1) exception handler around my route:

```
val exceptionHandler = ExceptionHandler {
    case e: DeserializationException => complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest, ServiceBrokerError(e.getMessage))
}
```

2) JSON format in implicit scope for `DeserializationException`

```
implicit object DeserializationExceptionFormat extends DefaultJsonProtocol with RootJsonFormat[DeserializationException] {

  def write(e: DeserializationException) = JsObject("message" -> JsString(e.getMessage))
  def read(v: JsValue) = throw new NotImplementedError()

}
```

Neither of these make any difference and `DeserializationException`s are still encoded in to the http response body per below:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 74
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 21:23:11 GMT
Server: akka-http/10.0.1

The request content was malformed:
Node count may not be a floating number
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Some additional context- my routes rely on the spray-json integration to map request entities to objects, such as:

```
// service instance management related routes
put {
  entity(as[CreateInstance]) { createInstance => handleCreateInstance(s"cluster-$clusterId", createInstance) }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should've just looked at `MarshallingDirectives.entity` as it does swallow serialization related exceptions and turn them in to Rejections:

```
/**
    * Unmarshalls the requests entity to the given type passes it to its inner Route.
   * If there is a problem with unmarshalling the request is rejected with the [[Rejection]]
   * produced by the unmarshaller.
   *
   * @group marshalling
   */
  def entity[T](um: FromRequestUnmarshaller[T]): Directive1[T] =
    extractRequestContext.flatMap[Tuple1[T]] { ctx ⇒
      import ctx.executionContext
      import ctx.materializer
      onComplete(um(ctx.request)) flatMap {
        case Success(value) ⇒ provide(value)
        case Failure(RejectionError(r)) ⇒ reject(r)
        case Failure(Unmarshaller.NoContentException) ⇒ reject(RequestEntityExpectedRejection)
        case Failure(Unmarshaller.UnsupportedContentTypeException(x)) ⇒ reject(UnsupportedRequestContentTypeRejection(x))
        case Failure(x: IllegalArgumentException) ⇒ reject(ValidationRejection(x.getMessage.nullAsEmpty, Some(x)))
        case Failure(x) ⇒ reject(MalformedRequestContentRejection(x.getMessage.nullAsEmpty, x))
      }
    } & cancelRejections(RequestEntityExpectedRejection.getClass, classOf[UnsupportedRequestContentTypeRejection])
```

Therefore it is a Rejection I must handle, and not the DeserializationException.

Answer (score 1):

What if you change your exception handler to

`val exceptionHandler = ExceptionHandler {
     case e: DeserializationException => complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest, e)
  }`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's the same output. I don't think the problem is the encoding of the ServiceBrokerError object, or at least I was hoping there would be something logged about it..